# Map::insert does not work

Tags: c++, stl

I am using this code to insert some elements to the map.

```
raw.insert({ std::string(name), new raw_resource(data, length) });
```

First element inserts succesfully, but second one does not.
Map type is

```
std::map<std::string, raw_resource*, compare> raw;
```

Comparator code

```
class compare
{
public:
    bool operator()(std::string s1, std::string s2)
    {
        return (s1.compare(s2) == 0);
    }
};
```

Comment: `std::map` accepts only unique keys. If key is already inserted, insertion fails.

Comment: Define "does not work" and adapt the title so the problem is neatly summarized.

Comment: Short observation: Using raw pointers is a bad idea, `unique_ptr` does not have any overhead but would plug that hole.

Comment: @user2864740, it returns pair with false as second value and does not insert.

Comment: Obviously you either have a duplicated key already inserted or your comparator screws things up.

Comment: Trying to use multimap and it works. But why does it fail if 'name' always different?

Comment: @40two added comparator code.

Comment: That's not a legal comparator for `std::map`. Just use the default one - you are not trying to do anything special anyway.

Comment: Listen to @T.C he's wise!

Comment: @T.C., thanks, but I used `std::map::find` with 100% existing key and it returned `map::end()` so I tried to use my own comparator.

Comment: @DejaVu `but I used std::map::find with 100% existing key and it returned map::end()`  Which means that the key didn't exist "100%".

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, http://c2n.me/iJMkDf.png

Comment: @DejaVu - I see "test-vs" and "test_vs".  They are not the same string.  But think about it -- if the compiler's `map::find` was this broken, would you even think about using that `map` class for anything?  Why would you want to write a compare function for a map class that you believed is broken?  I would probably not even use that entire compiler suite, let alone the `map` class.

Comment: @DejaVu your comparator is comparing elements as `==`, but compare function in std::map is expected to be `std::less` or functor with same behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the reference:

```
template<
    class Key,
    class T,
    class Compare = std::less<Key>,
    class Allocator = std::allocator<std::pair<const Key, T> >
> class map;
```

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map

An [std::map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) takes a comparator that tells if the first argument is less than the second. Not if they are equal. Otherwise it could not build a binary tree.

You don't need to write your own comparator for [std::string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) at all. All the comparison operators are already defined for you: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp.